# How to Disable Tooltip from OOB Web Part

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, web-part

I have added a couple of OOB WebParts on my SharePoint Page. When I hoverover the mouse pointer over that web part, it shows some help (tootip text about that web part). I want to disable that tooltip, How i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the page in SharePoint Designer and then use below snippet which goes and removes the ToolTip.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("[name='title']").attr('title','');
    });
</script>
```